# Jruby 1.6 added support for c native extension, but how do you build gems with c extensions?

Tags: windows, makefile, jruby, native

**Yea pretty much it. On windows xp sp3. This is what happens:**

jruby -S gem install a_gem_with_c_extensions

failed to build a_gem_with_c_extensions

could not find make command

Do i need cygwin, mingw, ruby dev-kit ?

Why it's not documented ? Native extension support feature has been out like 7 months now but no one has ever written one line to teach how to set it up?

Comment: Before downvoting read my own answer... If it is not clear, the reason I deleted the "devkit" folder (after running "dk.rb init" and "dk.rb install") is that I thought that those two commands had copied the compiling environment to a subfolder of the ruby path, so that the original folder was not needed anymore. I don't like to keep clutter on my hd and, as far as I can remember, the devkit installation output message was also misleading in that sense, telling something like "DevKit has been installed" instead of a more appropriate message like "DevKit environment folder has been configured".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found what i was doing wrong:

of course the easy way on windows is with ruby devkit but i did something wrong while i was following installation instruction:

1. Download the current DevKit-tdm-...-sfx.exe file from here.
2. Run the self-extracting executable and select to extract it in C:\RubyDevKit.
3. After the extract is done, open up a Ruby command prompt and navigate to C:\RubyDevKit.
4. Run the following commands:

ruby dk.rb init

ruby dk.rb install

I did it exactly as above at the time, but then **I erroneously thought that C:\RubyDevKit was not needed anymore and deleted the whole folder, thus resulting in gem devkit scripts not being able to find the "make" command, located in C:\RubyDevKit\bin**

fixed it like this: execute again all the steps above, but use --force option on last command: ruby dk.rb install --force

oh, and don't delete C:\RubyDevKit* afterward :)

Hope this can help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a functional build environment to compile the C extension. What all you need will depend on the C extension you are building. I'd start with installing Cygwin and getting it all set up. You may also want to note that C extension support in JRuby is still considered experimental according to their [wiki page](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives) so the extension you are trying to build may or may not work.

Or look here, seems DevKit is the preferred method of building C extensions on Windows:

["JRuby, Windows, and C Extensions"](http://jonforums.github.com/ruby/2010/11/30/devkit-jruby-c-extensions.html) - It looks like a nice turorial but it's a year old now.

Have a look at ["JRuby-on-Windows C extension building"](http://old.nabble.com/JRuby-on-Windows-C-extension-building-td29401822.html) as well

Comment: yea devkit is the preferred method on windows, but i made a mistake resulting in a corrupted devkit installation. Details following in my "self-answer" :)